# Does $f'$ have to be uniformly continuous or even continuous for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ to exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable function such that $ f'(x) $ uniformly continuous. If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L$ for some $L$, does $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ exist? **Does $f'$ have to be necessarily uniformly continuous for $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ to exist?**

> I saw this question [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023695/does-lim-limits-x-rightarrow-inftyfx-exist) but my attempt for a proof doesn't take into account the need for $f'$ to be uniformly continuous. Is it necessary for $f'$ to be uniformly continuous? If yes, please pinpoint the error which I might have made.

**Attempt:** $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)=L \implies ~\forall~\epsilon>0, \exists k \in \Bbb N~|~~|f(x)-L|< \epsilon~\forall~x>k~~\cdots (A)$.

Suppose $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ does not exist. $\implies \exists \epsilon \in \Bbb R^+~|~\forall M\in \Bbb R,N \in \Bbb R^+,~|f'(x)-M|~>\epsilon~\forall x> N $

Thus, Either $f'(x)<M-\epsilon$ or $f'(x)>M+\epsilon$ $\big(~f'$ cannot satisfy both because by Darboux Theorem, $f'$ will have to take values in between as well$\big)$. Suppose $f'(x)>M+\epsilon$.

Let $\max \{k,N \}=P$

By M.V.T , $\forall ~x >P :\dfrac {f(x)-f(P)}{x-P}  = f'(\delta)> M+ \epsilon $ for some $\delta \in (P,x)$

$ \implies f(x) > f(P)+(x-P)(M+\epsilon)~\forall~ x > P$ and hence, $f$  will not satisfy the limit criterion bringing a contradiction.

> **So, my query is: was uniform continuity of $f'$ or even continuity of $f$  necessary for this question?**

Comment: $\implies \exists \epsilon \in \Bbb R^+~|~\forall M\in \Bbb R,N \in \Bbb R^+,~|f'(x)-M|~>\epsilon~\forall x> N$ this line is wrong. Should be $(\forall M\in\mathbb{R})(\exists\epsilon>0)(\forall N\in\mathbb{R})(\exists x>N)(|f'(x)-M|\geq\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f\colon (0,\infty)\to\Bbb R$ given by
$$f(x)=\frac{\sin e^x}x.$$

After that, check again how to negate existence of the limit.

Comment: Thank you. Could you pin point any error in my proof please?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $f'$ does not even have to be continuous. You can have a differentiable $f$ which behaves like $\frac{1}{n}(x-n)^2 \sin((x-n)^{-1})$ near positive integers $n$, and is $0$ elsewhere. Such a function will satisfy $f'(x) \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$ but $f'$ is discontinuous at positive integers $n$.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it as well. That means my proof is correct?

Comment: @MathMan Well, if your proposed claim admits a counterexample, that's generally a sign that there exists a flaw in your proof.

Comment: But I proved that it does not need to be continuous !

Answer (score 1):

We can take the function $f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac{1}{x})$  ,if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

$f'(x)\to 1$ as $x\to +\infty$ but $f'$ is not even continuous.